# How to Get Round off Current Hour in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, hour

I need to get the round of current hour, for an example date **28/05/2021 2:16 PM** , but i need **28/05/2021 2:00 PM** just ignore the minute.

Answer (score 1):

This sould work

```cs
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime formattedDate = date.AddMinutes(-date.Minute);
```

Or

```cs
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime formattedDate = date.Date.AddHours(date.Hour);
```

to also exclude the seconds

Comment: Hi Rafael Duarte, 
   Second One working fine Thanks for given the answer.

DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime formattedDate = date.Date.AddHours(date.Hour);